# How to cancel previous Firebase Test Lab runs when starting a new one?

Tags: android, firebase, gcloud, firebase-test-lab

I'm using Firebase Test Lab to run automated tests for my Android application. I have a GitHub Actions workflow that triggers the Firebase Test Lab test runs whenever there's a new commit on the pull request.

The tests are running successfully, but I encountered a scenario where a new workflow run was triggered while the previous test run was still in progress. This led to multiple test runs running simultaneously, which is not ideal.

I want to find a way to cancel the previous Firebase Test Lab runs automatically whenever a new workflow run is started on the same branch. This will ensure that only the latest test run is executed and avoid resource wastage.

I've looked into the Firebase Test Lab documentation and explored the gcloud CLI options. I found that there is a ['cancel'](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/reference/testing/rest#rest-resource:-v1.projects.testmatrices) endpoint.

> POST /v1/projects/{projectId}/testMatrices/{testMatrixId}:cancel
> Cancels unfinished test executions in a test matrix.

But it needs a 'testMatrixId' and I only found a way to get this Id after the test execution. So that's not helpful.

Has anyone faced a similar situation or found a solution for cancelling previous Firebase Test Lab runs when a new one starts?

Answer (score 1):

To cancel previous Firebase Test Lab runs when a new one starts, you can use the Firebase Test Lab REST API to retrieve the test matrix IDs for the ongoing test runs and cancel them.

Here's a possible approach to achieve this:

1. Create a Firebase Test Lab Matrix:
   When starting a new test run, create a Firebase Test Lab matrix using the Test Lab REST API. This will initiate the test run and return a unique testMatrixId for the matrix.
2. Cancel ongoing test matrices:
   Iterate through the list of ongoing test matrices retrieved in the previous step and cancel each test matrix using the testMatrixId and the cancel endpoint you mentioned in your question.

   To cancel a test matrix, make a POST request to the following endpoint:

   POST /v1/projects/{projectId}/testMatrices/{testMatrixId}:cancel